# Why is python returning no result to my file search?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

I'm making a small tool that will be used to return a 1 or 0 output based off of if the current user has a file or folder in a specific path. As of now i haven't set it to be for a return 1 or 0 and instead just tells me if i have it. I'm using the os module to scan for it, though im not very experienced in using it. i know i have Git for windows installed at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. when i run my search for Git however, it shows nothing. here's my code.:

```
import os

def search_for_file_or_folder(root_dir, target_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=False):
        # Check if the target_name matches any of the subdirectories
        for dir_name in dirs:
            if dir_name == target_name:
                print(f"Found folder: {os.path.join(root, dir_name)}")

        # Check if the target_name matches any of the files
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name == target_name:
                print(f"Found file: {os.path.join(root, file_name)}")
userCU = os.getlogin()
# Specify the root directory (e.g., the "Downloads" folder)
DownloadsPath = f"C:\\Users\\{userCU}\\Downloads"
ProgramDataPath = f"C:\\Users\\{userCU}\\ProgramData"
print(f"current user: {userCU}")
# Specify the target folder or file name you want to search for
target_name = input("file/folder to search for:\n> ")

search_for_file_or_folder(DownloadsPath, target_name)
search_for_file_or_folder(ProgramDataPath, target_name)
```

I tried messing around with the topdown argument which i believe determines whether os.walk traverses hidden folders as well. i considered having it search for both casings of Git but i don't think it would help. this is honestly likely to be a simple path mistake or my misunderstanding of how the os module works.

Comment: The files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs are usually *.lnk files. Are you sure you have the correct filename, including the extension? (On my system it's "Git for Windows.lnk".)

Comment: when i search ffor Git.lnk, i get the same result. also, the Git im looking for is a folder.

Comment: Try printing all the names that os.walk finds, even if they don't match `target_name`. This might give you some clues as to what's going on (like whether the name is not what you expect, or if whole directories are being missed, etc)

Comment: Also, your pasted code of course won't find anything in C:\ProgramData\... because the paths it looks for are in C:\Users... But I guess what you pasted may be not literally exactly what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

My `ProgramDataPath` was incorrect. there is no `C:\Users\myuser\ProgramData`. its just in `C:\ProgramData`. My apologies for wasting your time and thank you for the suggestions